# Generate random points satisfying linear constraints

Tags: python, math, optimization, constraint-satisfaction

In my problem, I have a vector **x** of len N. Where each element **x<sub>i,j</sub>** is the price of the product i in the country j. Let's say that I have 100 products and 20 countries, so N=100x20=2000.

The solution of **X** is subject to a set of linear constraints. For instance, minimum/maximum price for each product and maximum difference allowed for the same product between countries. Therefore, I can define the constraints as a matrix **Ax<=b**

I guess the problem would be like sampling points from a space bounded by hyperplanes defined by the constraints.

Assuming that the problem has multiple feasible solutions. How can I generate random points (solutions of the vector **x**) that satisfy the constraints? Or there is any library that could help me with that?

I tried with https://github.com/python-constraint/python-constraint, but it seems that because the number of solutions is very large, the algorithm gets stuck at some point or takes a long time to return the solution.

Comment: Can you explain better the "maximum difference allowed for the same product between countries" constraint? Does the max diff change for each product, and/or for each country pair? In other words do you define `max_diff` as a single value, as `max_diff(Px)`, `max_diff(Ci,Cj)` or `max_diff(Px,Ci,Cj)`?

Comment: For instance, the maximum difference among the differents prices of product A in the 20 countries should be below a certain threshold. Therefore the maximum difference is defined for each product.

Comment: Are there requirements for the distribution? It ought to be easy to generate one solution, then go on a random walk.

Comment: @Slevin_42 Assuming that this is (close to) the real problem setup, wouldn't you want to optimize the solution `x` for something rather than choosing it completely at random?

Comment: @Beta there are no requirements for the distribution.

Comment: @a_guest the selection of the optimal solution is not in the scope of the problem. It would be done once all the solutions are evaluated by multiple factors (not only one that could be defined in an objective function). It should be done afterwards, not by me.

Comment: @Slevin_42 I was asking because with [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) you can minimize a cost function subject to such constraints, e.g. with [`scipy.optimize.linprog`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html). In case the distribution of sampled feasible solutions does not matter you can still use the `linprog` function; it will give you a delta distribution featuring one specific solution.

Comment: @a_guest and what cost function I can use in order to generate different random solutions? I tried myself with linear programming  (cvxpy library) using random cost functions (I generate randomly the vector c). The problem with this, is that most part of the time I'm on the borders of the solutions, I guess because is trying to minimize/maximize the cost function.

Comment: Try rejection sampling. Generate random x (unconstrained), then filter out any not meeting the constraint A . x <= b. Rejection sampling is very simple, it's a good way to get started. If it is not efficient enough (i.e., too small a fraction are left after filtering) then you'll have to try something else.

Comment: @Slevin_42 If you give it a constant cost function it should always return the same solution. But, referring to your previous comment, it seems like you could optimize the solution directly in the solver. You wrote *"[the selection of the optimal solution] would be done once all the solutions are evaluated by multiple factors (not only one that could be defined in an objective function)"*. I'm having difficulties to imagine what you mean here. Could you provide a simplified example, consisting of a set of conditions and all feasible solutions and then show how you would select the optimal one?

Comment: @RobertDodier I tried rejection sampling and it's not efficient enough... it seems that the possible price range for some products is very narrow after considering all the constraints. Therefore, most part of the random x generated don't satisfy all the constraints at the same time

Comment: @a_guest It doesn't return always the same solution since I set randomly some of the elements of the vector c equal to zero and I set randomly also the sign of them. Therefore, in the solutions, I minimize or maximize randomly the price of different products. Regarding the selection of the optimal solution, let's say the people from business are responsible for that. And they choose a solution in which the gross margin is above a threshold X and the profit is above a threshold Y, but they don't want the most extreme solutions.

Comment: @Slevin_42 If `c` is the coefficient vector for the linear programming and it contains non-zero elements, then the cost function is non-constant. But anyway, you need to be more specific about the actual problem you are trying to solve because otherwise we might be facing an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Right now, you posted a simplified version of your problem as a question on SO and you got an answer from @gimix but then you apparently realized that this doesn't solve your original problem. So if you want a solution for your original problem, you need to describe it.

Comment: @Slevin_42 It's also difficult to see how you would benefit from randomly drawing from feasible solutions. You say the business people would select an optimal solution from it but what if the random samples all are far from the actual optimum? Also, the business people need some algorithm for their decision, so perhaps this could be incorporated in the problem directly. And because randomly drawing from feasible solutions is a rather exotic thing to do, it would probably be more efficient to look at the bigger picture and to solve the entire problem at once.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, or you simplified a bit too much your actual use case. But for the case as stated there's no need for Constraint Programming:

- You have `min_price`, `max_price`, and `max_diff` for each product (I'm assuming `max_diff <= max_price - min_price`)
- So the actual minimum price you can set will be anywhere between `min_price` and `max_price - max_diff`. Let's say you set it at random in that range
- Accordingly the actual maximum price will be `actual_min + max_diff`
- Now the price of that product for each country will simply be a value between `actual_min` and `actual_max`.

I implemented this in a 3-steps process: create (random) data for the product (you will skip this one); compute the actual min/max values; and finally assign the prices for each product/country. At about 1300 solutions per second on my old i5 windows notebook for 100 products and 20 countries, it is even not so slow as one could have expected

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from random import choices, randint

@dataclass
class Product:
    min_price : int
    max_price : int
    max_diff : int
    actual_min : int = 0
    actual_max : int = 0

class Prices():
    def __init__(self, no_products, no_countries):
        self.products = {}
        for i in range(no_products):
            min_price = randint(100,200)
            max_price = min_price + randint(200,300)
            max_diff = randint(10,max_price - min_price)
            self.products[i] = Product(min_price, max_price, max_diff)
        self.countries = [c for c in range(no_countries)]
        self.prices = []

    def calc_actuals(self):
        for p in self.products.values():
            p.actual_min = randint(p.min_price, p.max_price - p.max_diff)
            p.actual_max = p.actual_min + p.max_diff

    def calc_prices(self):
        self.prices = []
        for p in self.products.values():
            self.prices.append([*choices(range(p.actual_min, p.actual_max+1),k=len(self.countries))])
```

Comment: this solution is quite interesting. Unfortunately, you are right I simplified the use case. I have a third type of constraint based on a hierarchy of prices (product A can't have a higher price than product B) that I omitted in the description of the problem by simplicity. This constraint is like a ranking that the products need to satisfy within each country (not necessary between countries). product a > product b > product c ... etc